# Selecting last observations of each item and count the results R

Tags: r, dplyr

The data (below an extract) consist of companies for which each observation contains info about companies for one year. Each company has a unique identifier `gvkey` (first column). The variable `costat` may take two forms "A" or "I".

I would like to select the last observation for each company with the value "I" in the variable `costat` and count the number of times each of the values in column `dlrsn` comes up per year (column "year"). The variable `dlrsn` can take number from 1 to 14. I want to know how many times each number comes up every year (column `fyear`) after selecting the last observation for each company.

I would like an answer using `dplyr`, if possible

Expected output assuming there would be only 5 years and two possible values for "dlrsn":

```
#   year dlrsn1 dlrsn2
# 1 1977      1      0
# 2 1989      0      1
```

where dlrsn1 = 9 (as in the data) and dlrsn2 = 7.

Dataframe below

```
    dput(example)
structure(list(gvkey = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1003L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L), fyear = c(1973L, 1974L, 
1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
1989L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L), costat = c("I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), dlrsn = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sale = c(37.75, 
50.325, 51.192, 66.414, 77.946, 13.793, 13.829, 24.189, 36.308, 
37.356, 32.808, 19.267, 57.312, 54.626, 65.797, 80.535, 92.82, 
118.667, 130.617, 132.482, 175.924, 155.006, 177.762, 218.946, 
248.012, 298.192, 347.64, 406.36, 444.875, 466.542)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am not sure how to even start. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We `filter` the rows where `costat` values are `"I"`, then grouped by 'gvkey', set the last row (`slice_tail` with `n = 1`), convert the `dlrsn` column to integer index by either `match`ing the values with `unique` value or use `factor` with `levels` specified and convert to `integer` , then reshape with `pivot_wider` to return the wide format from dlrsn column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
example %>% 
  filter(costat == "I") %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(dlrsn = as.integer(factor(dlrsn, levels = unique(dlrsn)))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(fyear), names_from = dlrsn, 
  values_from = dlrsn, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, 
   names_prefix = "dlrsn")
```

-output

```
  # A tibble: 2 × 3
  fyear dlrsn1 dlrsn2
  <int>  <int>  <int>
1  1977      1      0
2  1989      0      1
```